# How can I establish connection between backbone.js on localhost?

Tags: jquery, html, backbone.js

I am new to backbone.js , my que is how we can communicate local host with backbone.js. I have made sample programs that will deals with  [Heroku App](http://backbonejs-beginner.herokuapp.com) . As far as I know we need index.html , something.php in the same folder that will include all request like GET , POST, How we can communicate backbone.js on localhost?

Comment: Backbone generates the HTTP requests by using model functions like `save` and `fetch`... You **will** need a server to respond to these requests... Other than that I'm not too sure what you are asking here...

Comment: The documentation is here - http://backbonejs.org/#Sync - the specifics would depend on what your backend is written in, they give a Ruby example.